# Pentaho Report Designer PDF export is not showing the telugu characters

Tags: pdf, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have created a report using Pentaho Report Designer and it contains Telugu characters. When I try to export the report into PDF, I am not getting the Telugu   characters in PDF. Instead of Telugu characters it's showing as empty in PDF.

When I try to export into Excel, Telugu characters are displaying.

Someone help me to resolve this .

Comment: Are you using Report Designer in your PC? Or are you uploading the report created to a server and generating the PDF from the server?

Comment: yes ,Iam using report designer in my pc .

Comment: yes ,Iam using report designer in my pc .  In my pc after  exporting to pdf telugu characters are displaying but spelling mistakes in telugu characters and in the server it showing empty.

Answer (score 0):

This [solution](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/84477-Unable-to-display-characters-with-accent-on-pdf-view) was posted in the old pentaho forums for an old version of report designer, so the paths might have changed, but check if the options are available for your version:

From the menu bar: File - Configuration. Then in the Edit Report Configuration window, click output-pageable-pdf, check the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the problem is located in the server, it works in local. In that case check the fonts installed in the server, it might not have the font you are using in local, so the problem might be that the server is creating the PDF using another font without Telugu characters.

Comment: actually in local also telugu spellings are incorrect and im using nirmala ui font

Comment: I already installed telgu font in server  which i used in report designer but in html viewer its working ,in pdf telugu words are not correct .

Answer (score 0):

For the above issue ,I did something but then also iam struck.

actually i downloaded the telugu fonts and add that fonts into the server after i tried to generate the report .In html its perfectly fine but in pdf again telugu fonts are not correct.

So please if anyone could be suggest to move forward .

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't help anymore with this issue, but I think in this case the issue is more likely to be a problem with the PDF installation in the server, I remember vaguely that our server administrator had to add fonts specifically to the service used by the server to output to PDF. Maybe you might have more luck looking into that, I don't think in this case is a Pentaho issue.